# Position not updating over network

Tags: java, sockets, networking, graphics

I've written some simple code that allows a user to move a ball using the keyboard. I've connected a client and server using sockets to see if the client's ball would move in correspondence with the server's. The movement works, but in the client's panel, the ball is not getting repainted and is redrawing itself, last position still apparent. Below is the code for the client and its server.

**CLIENT**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class MovingBallClient extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private static Socket conn;
    //Updates movement
    private int x, y;
    private static boolean left, right, up, down;
    private Timer tm;

    public static void main(String[]  args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Client");
        MovingBallClient p = new MovingBallClient();
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(p);
        conn = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 2000);
        while(true)
        {
            try{
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                String dir = dis.readUTF();
                if(dir.equals("left"))
                {
                    left  = true;
                }
                else if(dir.equals("right"))
                {
                    right = true;
                }
                else if(dir.equals("up"))
                {
                    up = true;
                }
                else if(dir.equals("down"))
                {
                    down = true;
                }
            }catch(IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public MovingBallClient() throws UnknownHostException, IOException
    {
        x = y = 50;
        tm = new Timer(5, this);
        tm.start();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(left)
        {
            x -= 5;
            left = false;
        }
        else if(right)
        {
            x += 5;
            right = false;
        }
        else if(up)
        {
            y -= 5;
            up = false;
        }
        else if(down)
        {
            y += 5;
            down = false;
        }
        repaint();  
    }
}
```

**SERVER**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class MovingBallServer extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener{
    private int x, y;
    private boolean left, right, up, down;
    private Timer tm;
    private static ServerSocket server;
    private static Socket conn;
    private DataOutputStream dos;

    public MovingBallServer() throws UnknownHostException, IOException
    {
        x = y = 50;
        tm = new Timer(5, this);
        tm.start();
        left = right = up = down = false;
        setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(this);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Server");
        MovingBallServer p = new MovingBallServer();
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.add(p);
        server = new ServerSocket(2000, 1, InetAddress.getLocalHost());
        conn = server.accept();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        int k = e.getKeyCode();
        if(k == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
            up = true;
        else if(k == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
            down = true;
        else if(k == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
            left = true;
        else if(k == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
            right = true;
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
    {       
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
    {
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {   
        if(right && x <= 430)
        {
            x += 5;
            right = false;
            try{
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeUTF("right");
            }catch(IOException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(left && x >= 5)
        {
            x -= 5;
            left = false;
            try{
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeUTF("left");
            }catch(IOException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(up && y >= 5)
        {
            y -= 5;
            up = false;
            try{
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeUTF("up");
            }catch(IOException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(down && y <= 405)
        {
            y += 5;
            down = false;
            try{
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeUTF("down");
            }catch(IOException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: You likely have a thread memory reference issue. Try add `volatile` to the direction variables or use `AtomicBoolean` instead

Comment: I'd also strongly recommend using the key bindings API over `KeyListener`